# Aggregate item data from Zabbix?

Tags: triggers, zabbix

I would like to have Zabbix monitor different items (on the same host, or on different hosts) and assign a value depending on the outcome, then have it fire (or not) a trigger depending on the aggregation of these values.

For instance, let's imagine a cluster of 3 database nodes.  Zabbix monitors every one of them via ping and increases a global variable by 1 if the node is reachable.  After a round, the variable could have the following values:

- 3 => (all nodes are up) cluster is OK
- 2 => (one node is down) cluster is still working but in degraded state
- 1 => (two nodes are down) cluster is working but no replication is done
- 0 => (all nodes are down) cluster is down

Then Zabbix fires a trigger with WARNING severity if value is 1, and a trigger with HIGH severity if value is 0.

Is there a way to do this natively or via a module, without having to use the APIs?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to aggregate data from several items into one, you can either use [aggregate items](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/2.4/manual/config/items/itemtypes/aggregate) or [calculated items](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/2.4/manual/config/items/itemtypes/calculated). Aggregate items allow to aggregate all items with the same key in the specified host groups, whereas calculated items allow arbitrary operations on items based on a formula.

In order to have two triggers with different severities, you may find [trigger dependencies](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/2.4/manual/config/triggers/dependencies) useful. Here, a trigger with a lower dependency would depend on a trigger with a higher dependency.

Comment: For instance, grpsum[Cluster,icmpping,last] would evaluate to the number of reachable nodes in "Cluster" group.

Comment: Regarding the first comment, I do not think that "sum(icmpping)" makes a lot of sense. It should rather be something like "last(host1:icmpping)+last(host2:icmpping)+last(host3:icmpping)+..." for every host that make up your cluster.

Comment: Regarding the second comment, the error message you showed is probably for the calculated item, not the aggregate item.

Comment: Thanks. I removed a couple of my previous comments to avoid confusion, as what I wrote was wrong. Would like to upvote your answer but I don't have enough rep.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks.  Following your advice, I managed to do what I wanted.  Here are the steps:

1. create a host group my_DB_cluster and populate it with the nodes' IP addresses;
2. create a new template my_template and add it to the host group my_DB_cluster;
3. inside my_template, create a new item with key grpsum[my_DB_cluster,icmpping,last,0];
4. create a new value mapping and associate it to the item's results, in order to get a message ("cluster is down") instead of a simple value (0);
5. inside my_template, create triggers with different severity on key grpsum[my_DB_cluster,icmpping,last,0].